# How many degrees of freedom does a symplectic form have?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

A symplectic 2-form on a $2n$ dimensional manifold has to be closed, nondegenerate and antisymmetric. My question is: Do these conditions imply how many degrees of freedom the symplectic form has?

I know that any antisymmetric matrix will have $\frac{\big(2n\big)^2-2n}{2}$ but how do I account for the fact that it also has to be closed and nondegenerate?

Comment: It looks like at a single point $p$ of your manifold, you have anti-symmetry and nondegeneracy ($\det\omega_p = 0$) which reduces the freedom by 1 more. Then the coefficients must satisfy the (some number of) differential equations given by the closed criterion $d\omega =0$. It may be infinite degrees of freedom for the whole form. I am imagining adding some compactly supported, closed, antisymmetric perturbation $\eta$, small enough that $\omega + \eta$ is still nondegenerate.